# How can I get a specific value from an object?

Tags: jquery, object

I am creating an object and want to output the value of `id`:

```js
   var result = {};
  $.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });  
  
  console.log(result[id]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```

The result I expect is `23`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because the browser believes that `id` is a variable. You need to access it via either `result['id']` or `result.id` to get the property's value from the object:

**Example 1:** *Access property value using bracket notation*

```js
   var result = {};
  $.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });  
  
  console.log(result['id']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```

**Example 2:** *Access property value using object notation*

```js
   var result = {};
  $.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });  
  
  console.log(result.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must call `result['id']`or `result.id` since `id`is not declared as a variable

```js
   var result = {};
  $.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function() {
      result[this.name] = this.value;
  });  
  
  console.log(result.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to get the `name` and `value` property from the object which can get as the second argument. And get the property using [`['id']` or `.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) syntax.

```js
var result = {};
$.each($('.color input').serializeArray(), function(i, v) {
  result[v.name] = v.value;
});

console.log(result.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```

Or generate the object as follows by iterating simply using `each()` method on the jQuery input element collection.

```js
var result = {};
$('.color input').each(function() {
  result[this.name] = this.value;
});

console.log(result.id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color" style="background-color:pink">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="fred">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="23">
</div>
```